# Synchronous behavior when use methods of Java CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, executorservice, completable-future

I am using Java's CompletableFuture like this into a spring boot `@Service`:

```
@Service
public class ProcessService {

    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    @Autowired
    ChangeHistoryService changeHistoryService;

    public Attribute process(Attribute attribute) {
        //some code

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> changeHistoryService.logChanges(attribute), EXECUTOR);

        return attribute;
    }

}
```

The `process` method is called form a method inside a `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class ProcessController {


    @Autowired
    ProcessService processService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/processAttribute",
            method = {RequestMethod.POST},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Attribute applyRules(@RequestBody Attribute attribute) {

        Attribute resultValue = processService.service(attribute);

        return resultValue;
    }

}
```

`ChangeHistoryService::logChanges` only save some data to database according to its parameter. 
I have a microservice that makes a number of request to this "/processAttribute" endpoint and print all responses.

When I put a breakpoint in `logChanges` method, the microservice is waiting on some request but not all which makes me think that the `ChangeHistoryService::logChanges` not always runs async. If I don't supply the `runAsync` with a ExecutorService, the microservice blocks on more request but still not all.
From what I understood this is because method that process the request and `logChanges` method share same thread pool (ForkJoinPool?).
Anyway, as I have another ExecutorService, `logChanges` should not runs independently? Or is something about how IDE treats breakpoints on async task? I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the breakpoint suspends all threads and not only the thread that runs `logChanges` method. I fix this in Intellij IDEA by pressing right click on breakpoint and checked "Thread" checkbox, not "All":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather small threadpool, so it's no wonder that you can saturate it. The threads that process requests are not the same as the ones processing your `CompletableFutures`. One is an internal component of the server, and the second one is the one you explicitly created, `EXECUTOR`.

If you want to increase the asynchronousness, try giving `EXECUTOR` some more threads and see how the behaviour changes accordingly. Currently the `EXECUTOR` is a bottleneck, since there are far more threads available for requests to run in.

Note that by putting a breakpoint inside `logChanges()` you'll be blocking one thread in the pool, making it even more saturated.

Comment: Hi @Kayaman! From documentation of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`: 
>"If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available."

I don't understand why the thread that submitted the task blocks even if the threadpool is saturated. The task should be added to the queue, the submitter thread continues running and the task will be processed independently when will be an available thread. if I have a small threadpool the queue will continue to grow but don't blocks the submitter thread. That's not what it should be?

Comment: Is the code above your actual code? You're not doing anything stupid to prevent the request thread from keeping from executing, are you?

Comment: My actual code so I think I am not doing anything stupid to prevent the request thread from keeping from executing

Comment: Have you tried using `@Async` on `logChanges()`? How are you actually determining that it's not being run async? What kind of traffic are you putting to the server?